# Tuitanium Studio: [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

Tags: android, build, titanium

I have a project that was worked perfectly but now is not without changing any things
The other projects in my workspace work fine.
When I run the project it give me this error:

[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

I try that but without result:

- clean the project and delete the build folder
- Restart my pc, and Titanium Studio
- I reconfigure the android SDK and Titanium SDK with the command Titanium setup

Is there any other things that I ca do? How can I trace the log File in order to get the error of the project?

Comment: Is this Windows OS? Go to Studio Help menu > Studio > View Log File.  What is the console output of "ti info"?

Comment: have u resolved the issue ??

Comment: yes with using the command titanium -setup